# How can I upload multiple Forms into Forms Library and set some values?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, forms-library

I have a forms Library with over 6k Forms in it and I created a new one. As I cant move them directly because almost everything has been changed in the new form (new fields, etc) I need to create a form and copy some of the content from form A in old library to Form B in new library.

I read something about a master template (empty xml form) that I need to recreate for every new form in the new forms library. How to do that?